# Operation is not allowed - Picklist value Salesforce API

Tags: salesforce, jitterbit

I have a simple upsert operation using the Jitterbit data loader. I am trying to create a new **case** record in Salesforce. One of the attributes of the case object is the **case origin**. This is a picklist field. I want all case objects created using Jitterbit to have a certain origin value. Let's call that value "Company Core". When my upsert runs I always get the following error if Company Core is supplied as the value for case origin.

```
Operation is not allowed
```

If I omit the case origin then the upsert is always successful. If after insert I update the record and supply the case origin field then the update is also successful.

As a workaround I could first insert the record without a case origin and then subsequently update it but:
1. This is a suboptimal solution and shouldn't be necessary.
2. There are case assignment rules triggered on insert that rely on case origin having the correct value at the time of insert.

I can't find much online about anyone experiencing similar problems. Some posts hint that field level security might be involved but I've tried removing read-only without success.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000938xIAA

The account doing the data uploading is a system administrator account. The version of the Jitterbit data loader is **8.4.4.6**.

Thanks for your help.

**Field Level Security**

[image: Field Level Security]

**Field Accessibility**

[image: Field Accessibility]

Answer (score 0):

Even though the value we're inserting for Case Origin is never null checking the "Insert null values" check box resolves the problem. I recommend if possible your Operation Options be *exactly the same* as the screenshot below. This seems to be a Jitterbit related issue rather than a Salesforce API issue.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.

[image: Insert null values]